# Sencha dynamically adding to component not work in build

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Sencha Touch 2.2.1
Cmd 3.1.342

I have a sencha web app used to display data using Sencha Charts and carousel. The data is obtained via ajax. Components are created according to the amount of data that is received from the server.

Everything works fine in development. However, when I create a production build, the components are created, but not populated with the carousel and the app crashes. It seems that this happens when I try to add the carousel the carousel to the container using: `Ext.getCmp(siteNamex+'Cont').add(thecarousel);`

It then dies and console log says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined
>   Ext.ClassManager.parseNamespace
>   Ext.ClassManager.get
>   Ext.ClassManager.instantiate
>   Ext.ClassManager.instantiateByAlias
>   Ext.apply.factory
>   Ext.define.factoryItem
>   Ext.define.add
>   Ext.Ajax.request.success
>   Ext.apply.callback
>   Ext.define.onComplete
>   Ext.define.onStateChange (anonymous function)

Here is the code which creates the container:

```
newcontainer = Ext.Container({
        xtype : 'container',
        flex: 1,
        margin: '0',
        id: siteNamex+'Cont',
        itemId: siteNamex+'Cont',
        height: '100%',
        items: [], 
        cls:'siteContainer',
        html: '<h2 class="siteName" style="'+snStyle+'">'+siteName+'</h2>'
     });
```

This code seems to be working and creates the container as required.

Charts populate an array. The size depends on the data received via ajax:

```
var allcharts = new Array(); //initializing
```

Create gauge chart:

```
chartgx = Ext.chart.Chart({  
        xtype: 'chart',  
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),  
        cls: 'thegauge',  
        itemId: 'gauge'+tt2,  
        store: gaugeStore,  
        width : 'auto',  
        background: 'white',  
        animate: true,  
        insetPadding: 50,  
        axes: [{  
              type: 'gauge',  
              position: 'gauge',  
              minimum: 0,  
              maximum: gaugemax,  
              steps: 10,  
          margin: 10  
            }],  
            series: [{  
              type: 'gauge',  
              field: 'CurrentValue',   
              donut: 30,  
              colorSet: ['#f6821f;', '#e0e2e4']  
            }]  
        });
```

Then I put this gauge in a container and add to array:

```
chartgx2 = Ext.Container({  
        xtype : 'container',  
        flex: 1,  
        layout: 'fit',  
        cls: 'gaugeContainer',  
        items: chartgx,   
        html: gaugeText  
           })  
allcharts.push(chartgx2);
```

The carousel is then created using:

```
thecarousel = Ext.Carousel({
                        xtype: 'carousel',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%',
                        itemId: 'thecarousel_'+siteName,
                        cls: 'chartscarousel',
                        id: siteNamex+'_carousel',
                        defaults: {
                            styleHtmlContent:true
                        },
                        items: allcharts
                    })
```

and is added to the container using `Ext.getCmp(siteNamex+'Cont').add(thecarousel);`

As I said earlier, this all works fine in development, but in the production build it throws up the error mentioned.

My app.js has the following:

```
requires: [
        'Ext.field.Select',
    'Ext.Ajax',
    'Ext.Button',
    'Ext.carousel.Indicator',
    'Ext.carousel.Infinite',
    'Ext.carousel.Item',
    'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
    'Ext.fx.easing.EaseOut',
    'Ext.util.TranslatableGroup',
    'Ext.chart.Chart',
    'Ext.chart.axis.Gauge',
    'Ext.chart.theme.*',
    'Ext.util.Format',
    'Ext.MessageBox',
    'Ext.form.Panel',
    'Ext.Panel',
    'Ext.fx.Parser',
    'Ext.Container',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.dataview.List',
    'Ext.dataview.component.Container',
    'Ext.chart.theme.Base',
    'Ext.chart.theme.TitleStyle',
    'Ext.chart.theme.GridStyle',
    'Ext.chart.Toolbar',
    'Ext.chart.legend.View',
    'Ext.chart.Legend',
    'Ext.chart.series.Bar',
    'Ext.chart.series.Column',
    'Ext.chart.series.Gauge',
    'Ext.chart.series.Series',
    'Ext.chart.axis.Numeric',
    'Ext.chart.axis.Category',
    'Ext.draw.Surface',
    'Ext.draw.Draw',
    'Ext.draw.Matrix',
    'Ext.draw.engine.Canvas',
    'Ext.draw.CompositeSprite',
    'Ext.fx.Frame',
    'Ext.draw.Sprite',
    'Ext.fx.Sprite',
    'Ext.Component',
    'Ext.ComponentManager',
    'Ext.ComponentQuery',
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.draw.sprite.Sector',
    'Ext.draw.sprite.Rect',
    'Ext.chart.interactions.Abstract',
    'Ext.chart.axis.Axis',
    'Ext.util.SizeMonitor',
    'Ext.chart.grid.HorizontalGrid',
    'Ext.chart.grid.VerticalGrid'
    ],
```

When I run build command there are no errors.
Sencha Touch 2.2.1
Cmd 3.1.342

**Update:**
I rebuilt the gauge using [this code](http://docs.sencha.com/touch-charts/1.0.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Gauge) exactly as it appears on the page. This did not resolve the problem

Comment: It seems that the error lies in your `allcharts` array. May we see?

Comment: You're probably missing a require but I can't tell which.

Comment: That's what I thought. But, it's odd that the Android version works fine.

Comment: We have had a thorough debug session, and we think the missing require is related to the charts. We have been through Sencha Docs and added those that weren't already in app.js. Interestingly, the paths mentioned on Sencha Docs were not all correct

Comment: You know the way you create your components is very weird? That should be `new Ext.Carousel({...})`. It is possible that what you do modify the class and break the lib. Furthermore, components instantiated this way don't need the `xtype`. Anyway, regarding your question, you should have a warning in dev mode showing in the console, telling you that a require is missing... Isn't it the case?

Comment: @rixo: No warning in dev mode. I originally used your way of creating the carousel and still had the error. I added the xtype to try to fix this error, as I read somewhere that it was needed. It made no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would debug it like this:

1. Open your app in Chrome
2. Open dev tools
3. Go in "Sources" tab
4. Click two times on the pause symbol ("Pause on uncaught exceptions", bottom left arrow in the image bellow)
5. Do the thing that makes your application crash, or reload if it crashes on loading
6. The debugger will kick in just before throwing the exception you've noted
7. In the call stack, select the line `Ext.ClassManager.instantiateByAlias` (second arrow)
8. In the "Scope Variables" tab, you'll see the name of the culprit (circled bellow)

The variable name may be different because of the minification process, but you should be able to identify it easily. Optionally, you can disable compression in the file `.sencha/app/production.properties` to see the real code and make it easier.

[image: Chrome debugging]

Comment: Thanks for this. The error seems to be <exception>: TypeError
arguments: Arguments[2]
0: "axis.Gauge", yet I have 'Ext.chart.axis.Gauge', in my app.js requires

Comment: Are you sure the class `Ext.chart.axis.Gauge` exist at all? It is not mentioned in the docs. There's only a gauge series.

Comment: Indeed I was wrong, it is present in the ["Touch chart" docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch-charts/1.0.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.axis.Gauge); however it is not included in the base Touch package, neither in the docs nor in the sources.

Comment: Then again, I can't be sure this class hasn't been removed in Touch 2... The [example](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Gauge) in the docs doesn't use an axis. If I were you I would create my chart like in this example, and get rid of this problematic class altogether. Now, out of curiosity you can also check that the class correctly declares its `alias: 'axis.gauge'`; what you have in your SDK seems to be a phantom deprecated class which code may be outdated.

Comment: adding the alias to axis.gauge seems to resolve the issue for that file, but it is now with chart.series.Gauge - adding missing alias to that one hasn't rectified it.